# Servlet: How to get own URL pattern?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

**Can a servlet or filter look up its own URL pattern?**

Meaning, if I bind some servlet or filter to `/first/*` and `/second/*` and a request comes in, can I find out which of the two patterns triggered it?

Even if a servlet is bound only to one pattern, is there a way to look it up from inside the servlet (instead of hard-coding a value)?

Comment: Do you _actually_ want the pattern or just the URL?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I *actually* want the pattern ;)

Answer (score 8):

This method on the HttpServletRequest class will help you. You'll get an instance of HttpServletRequest on any of the Servlet methods invoked by a HTTP Request.

> getServletPath
>
> java.lang.String getServletPath() Returns the part of this request's
>   URL that calls the servlet. This path starts with a "/" character and
>   includes either the servlet name or a path to the servlet, but does
>   not include any extra path information or a query string. Same as the
>   value of the CGI variable SCRIPT_NAME.

Take a look at this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `<url-pattern>` registration for a servlet by

```
ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
ServletRegistration servletRegistration = servletContext.getServletRegistration();
java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> mappings = servletRegistration.getMappings()
```

and get the

```
final String path = getServletPath();
```

from `request` as Andreeas suggested and try to find out mapping by comparing string patterns

---

**Javadocs**

- [`servletRegistration.getMapping()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html#getMappings%28%29)
- [`servlet.getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29)
- [`servletContext.getServletRegistration()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: How I can get url pattern in servlet 2.5?? As servlet registration is not available in older version.

Comment: `servletContext.getServletRegistration()` does not exist, only `servletContext.getServletRegistration(String servletName)`. In order to use that one, you can override `GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig config)` and get the mappings by executing `Collection<String> mappings=getServletContext().getServletRegistration(config.getServletName()).getMappings();` in it. Also, `servletRegistration.getMapping()` does not exist. It should read `servletRegistration.getMappings()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want the URL mappings, there are a few ways, but they all require some information from the deployment.

For example, if you know the name of the Servlet, you can use [`ServletContext#getServletRegistration(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration%28java.lang.String%29)

```
ServletContext context = ...;
Collection<String> mappings = context.getServletRegistration("servlet-name").getMappings();
```

If you don't know the name, you can get them all with [`ServletContext#getServletRegistrations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistrations%28%29)

```
Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> registrations = context.getServletRegistrations();
```

and try to find yours, maybe by comparing classes (your servlet class versus the class name from the [`ServletRegistration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Registration.html#getClassName%28%29)).

Note that you will still probably have to try matching your current request's URL to the Servlet's url mappings to be sure. You'd have to go to the Specification to find out how the mappings actually work.

Comment: How I can  get url pattern in servlet 2.5?? As servlet registration is not available in older version.